# Python create dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am playing with BeautifulSoup and scraping bing search results. I don't plan on doing extensive scraping, I was just trying my hand at different data structures, etc.

What I'm trying to do is create a dictionary with the different parsed results from my scrape. In other words, I need to put the link as one value, meta (description) info in another value.

My end result should look something like this I would imagine:

```
{  '1' : {
     'link' : '<a href="watever">Whatever</a>',
     'description' : 'this is a great website'
   },
   '2' : {
     ... etc ...
   }
}
```

My current code looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import html5lib

url = requests.get("http://www.bing.com/search?q=pet+toys")

data = url.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")

for link in soup.find_all("li", "sa_wr"):
        record = {'link' : link.find_all("a")}

print record
```

I'm obviously fairly new to Python...in PHP, I would have this handled, I am still just working on Python syntax, etc.

Any help is appreciated.

**Solution:**

The code was working as it was supposed to, but I was seeing the dictionary with just one item as I was not iterating through it.

Also, per recommendation, I added each dictionary to a list as opposed to a dictionary.

```
records = []

for link in soup.find_all("li", "sa_wr"):
        for url in link.find_all("a"):
                records.append( {'link' : url.get("href"), 'title' : url.contents} )

for record in records:
        print record['title']
```

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. Whats it doing when you run it? How is it not working?

Comment: Why would you want a dictionary with integer keys instead of just a list?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to build a JSON database.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, It does appear to be working... I was just printing one record, I should have done a for loop to view all of the records.

Comment: @Alpinestar22 Please add your solution and accept it as answer or close this question.